# Race Condition in ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate

Tags: java

Im planning to use Strategy design pattern to put it in
ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate. I can use create as many scheduleAtFixedrate depends on the data to be pulled. Will this cause a race condition?

```
    public abstract class DefaultStrategy {
    
        protected Map<String, String> transactionMap;
        protected AuthParam authParam;
    
        public DefaultStrategy(Map<String, String> transactionMap, Projection projection) {
            this.transactionMap = transactionMap;
            this.projection= projection;
        }
    }
    
    public class BankStrategy extends DefaultStrategy implements Runnable{
    
        public BankStrategy (Map<String, String> transactionMap, Projection projection) {
            super(transactionMap, projection);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String transaction = transactionMap.get("branch1");
            String balance = projection.getBalance();
            // do something with transaction and balance
        }
    }
    
    public class LoanSharkStrategy extends DefaultStrategy implements Runnable{
    
        public LoanSharkStrategy(Map<String, String> transactionMap, Projection projection) {
            super(transactionMap, projection);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String transaction = transactionMap.get("branch2");
            String balance = projection.getBalance();
            // do something with transaction and balance
        }
    }



public class Handler {

    private static final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorServiceFirst = MDScheduledExecutorService.wrap(
            new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5), "first-thread-%d");

   //assuming this is the main method to call
   private void main() {
      //assuming there is a list of Param with transactionMap and projection that was populated in other function..
      List<Param> loanSharkStrategyParams = getParamsFromOtherFucnction();
      
      loanSharkStrategyParams.forEach(param -> {
        scheduledExecutorServiceFirst.scheduleAtFixedRate(new 
        LoanSharkStrategy(param.getTransactionMap, param.getProjection())), 1, 3600, SECONDS);
      });
     
   }      
 }
```